# if jquery live event code has been removed, do i still have to unbind it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, live

im loading pages with ajax and also loading pages javascript code with it.

i wanted to know, if i remove page javascript code, which has jquery live bind event on it, will it kill the binding or do i still have to call $(this).die(); function?

**jquery live bind event**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.showNavLink').live('click', function() {

    });
});
```

**Ajax Page Flow**

- home page is loaded
- home page javascript is loaded
- user requested to load new page (on click)
- removing home page code with javascript
- removing javascript code
- loading new page... (starts the cycle with first step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.live` is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/live/. But if you are using it, you should remove it. I'm assuming you're never refreshing the page. Just removing script tags doesn't undo everything that was done when the script was run.

The new way is

```
$(document).on('click', '.showNavLink', function() {});
```

When it's no longer needed

```
$(document).off('click', '.showNavLink');
```

Comment: Ah.. makes sense.. I was just wondering.. Haven't read the new changes yet

Comment: @JuanMendes what if i was using $(document).click(function(){}); do i still need to unbind this function too?

Comment: If you don't want the behavior to apply, yes, you do have to unbind it, otherwise, it will still happen. I'm not sure why you'd think you don't need to unbind in that case. In your original question, you're restricting the handler only to elements with class `navLink` so it wouldn't matter since you wouldn't have `navLink`s anymore? But you should still clean it up to conserve memory, and cleaning up after yourself is a good habit that will prevent bugs in the future

Comment: @JuanMendes well not only that, but from my past knowledge about click function, is that if new element is created, even if its same name. it wont get trigger. isn't that right?

Comment: Basit, you need to understand the what is happening is event delegation, the click event is attached to the document, so it gets notified of every click. jQuery will filter the events so that you only get notified if the target of the event matches the selector you've given. In the new way, you can have `on` work with event delegation just like `$.live` did.

Comment: @JuanMendes i have just did the test. i have setup two identical pages, one with $.click function and one without. when i go from one page to another with ajax. the function dont work anymore. seem like i dont have to unbind anymore!!!?

Comment: @Basit I already explained this, did you read my comment? `In your original question, you're restricting the handler only to elements with class navLink so it wouldn't matter since you wouldn't have navLinks anymore? But you should still clean it up to conserve memory, and cleaning up after yourself is a good habit that will prevent bugs in the future`

Comment: @JuanMendes i miss understood. but i head a question in head, what if new element still head same class name, then what? so i did test and it still looks fine, even if the new element head same name. unless we use delegated events.

Comment: @Basit I am not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "unless we use delegated events"? It's assumed you're using delegated events, otherwise the question doesn't even make sense. If you update all the elements on the page and create a new element with class `navLinks`, you don't need to rebind again, your handler will still work. If you know it won't be needed, you should remove the handler (unless you know it may come back again, in which case adding and removing handlers may be a source of bugs)

Comment: @JuanMendes i have implemented facebook BigPipe feature on my application and i have bind the element and removed it. after removing it, i have created the same element on the page again and the already existing bind didnt work. so i head to recreate the bind again. maybe you should try it too. browser was chrome on testing time.

Comment: @Basit You're doing something wrong, I'm 100% event delegation works just as I described. See this example where you can add divs dynamically and you never have to rebind http://jsfiddle.net/zWQM8/

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry if i confused you. i meant direct event ($('.link').click(function...));, not delegation one.

Comment: @Basit You confused yourself :) Your question is about `$.live` which is event delegation.

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes you are right, im very sorry for that. in middle i started to see if i can go any other way around it and thought its best to use direct method, since i dont have to remove them on new page load, it will be done automatically.

Comment: @Basit The event handler will not be removed automatically, it should get garbage collected if there aren't any cyclical references, but it's good form to remove the handlers yourself

Answer (score 2):

Removing the element **disassociates** all the events of the corresponding elements.

Even when you remove the elements there might be memory leaks  if you do not remove the events
.. So it is better  to explicitly  call `.die()`

Also

```
As of jQuery 1.7, use of .die() (and its complementary method, .live())
is not recommended. Instead, use .off() to remove event handlers bound with .on()
```

Comment: The events do not get disassociated if you're using event delegation, which is what `$.live` uses. The event is attached to the entire document. Therefore, removing the elements that were affected by the handler will not remove the `$.live` event

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Javascript source code won't remove the Javascript function objects that were created from that code.

You have to unbind the event handler to keep it from handling events.